# Javascript Injection Security Solutions

Tags: javascript, python, security

In short my question is, "How do I authenticate which client-side messages are coming from my code and which are coming from a hacker?"

I've read a lot of articles on Javascript injection and read a lot of answers here on StackOverflow. Unfortunately, the answer always given is some sort of "never trust the client, always authenticate requests". Sounds like good advice, but I can't figure out how to apply it to my situation. I've tried to close off all client-side access points to my server-side code, but I still have one and I need some help securing it. Here's my situation:

- I have two websites, www.main_site.com and www.storage.com
- For reasons I don't have time to go into, www.storage.com has control of databases and other various data storage devices that I don't want anyone getting their hands on.
- www.main_site.com has shared access to one of those databases, where I have a running cycle of keycodes that are sent with every request from www.main_site.com to www.storage.com. If the request is missing a keycode it shows a 404 page
- In the client-side JS of www.main_site.com, I make an AJAX request to www.storage.com asking for it to generate a keycode, put the keycode in the shared database, then tell me the location of the keycode in the db.
- Then the client-side JS makes a WebSocket request to the server of main_site.com, and the server searches the database and finds the keycode, returns it to the client.
- Then the client makes a GET request to www.storage.com with the query and the keycode. My code in the client of main_site.com looks like this:

  ```
  $.get("http://www.storage.com/make_code", function (location) {
      socket.emit("get_code", location, function (code) {
          $.get("http://www.storage.com/do_stuff?input="+input+"&code="+code, function (response) {
              //here I do whatever with the response
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I know there's a lot wrong with this code, but I've patched a lot of holes. I've made www.storage.com accept only requests from www.main_site.com by using the CORS policy among other patches. Mainly, the last big vulnerability I see and the one I want to tackle now is somebody using Dev Tools on Chrome or Firefox to insert JS that'll call all of this and simulate a real call. How can I implement server-side authentication here? I don't particularly mind someone calling the first $.get because it only makes a code and returns it's location in the database. I use extra ones for testing purposes. But once they call that socket.emit, they have access to do whatever they want. What options do I have, and maybe please give an example of how I might implement your suggestions in JavaScript or in Python (www.storage.com is in Python). Thanks!

--EDIT--
I can hack my own site right now by going to the Chrome dev tools console and typing exactly the code above. I can't prevent someone else from doing this, so what are some verification techniques commonly used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are 2 scenarios:

#### You want some user to have some data from storage.com

You have to make sure the resources you are sharing with a random user of main_site.com are not sensitive. If you want to restrict access to some data X on storage.com to only some users, they'll have to provide some credentials Y. You'll then map Y to X and check if everything is ok for each call.

You **cannot** have js alone provides these credentials, User must be implied.

#### You want to execute an automated task relying on data from storage.com

Js makes a call to main_site.com backend. It retrieves the data from storage.com through a secure channel (you can use a long shared token and https).

main_site.com then provides only the useful|not sensitive|preprocessed data to the frontend

Comment: Thanks! I use both options in this situation, but my question as specifically about the first. Sorry for being unclear about that. Your response is great, but I see a problem with it. The potential hackers I'm worried about are my users, and no user should ever see the data I'm getting from storage.com. I could have the user type in their password before getting the keycode, but if the hacker is a user, I can't rely on their trustworthiness. I'll definitely implement the credentials verification you mentioned, I'm just wondering if this will open up more security holes.

Comment: If each user has access only to his data and not to others, there will be no problem. Think a little about facebook. There are public pages whose posts are open to everyone, and private posts that everyone does not have access to. What I mean is that each user must be presented to a subset of the available information possibly consisting of one public part and the other, sensitive, protected by a password. That is, two different users will have different credentials giving them access to specific data that is only useful to them.

Comment: So assuming each user has access to a public area (which in my case there is one public area), what's to stop a malicious, but authorized user from going into Chrome Dev Tools and typing the code example in my original post? They could act as someone else by just typing the other person's username, and the hacker's password, and simply make AJAX and socket requests at will. Sorry if I'm not understanding this, I'm new and having trouble applying generic security advice to my situation.

Comment: Here to help ^_^. To make it clear, is it bad if someone has access to the public area while acting as someone else? Because he can't even pretend to be someone else in the first place. The username and password have to match and password is secret.

Comment: Even if he executes the code in the Dev tools he won't do any harm without perfect credentials (username + password). He will make the requests for sure but won't have anything he would have not had using the site normally

Comment: So it boils down to make sure an authorized user can't be malicious. His authorization must be not only a pass to his data, but pretty much also a prohibition of access to data that you do not want him to see. As for public data, they must be effectively free to access and not sensitive at all.

Answer (score 1):

> --EDIT-- I can hack my own site right now by going to the Chrome dev tools console and typing exactly the code above.

So here is the cruel truth... You can make it hard to hack but you cannot make it impossible!!!

This is true for web apps, for mobile apps a solution exists, but I am not digging on it once is out of scope for your situation.

> I can't prevent someone else from doing this, so what are some verification techniques commonly used?

You can read [this series](http://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of 
articles about Mobile Api Security Techniques to understand how they are implemented and bypassed. This articles are more in the context of an API for a mobile app but the majority of the techniques mentioned there can also be applied in a web app.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'll definitely look through that. Is there any advice you might give on better alternatives to obfuscating my code? I'm working with some others, so obfuscating while still in development isn't a great idea.

Comment: @JadenBaptista try this https://obfuscator.io/ but bear in mind that in dev tools you will still be able to see what goes over the wire.